# Fixing TypeError for Firebase Google Sign In Authentication

Tags: html, firebase, authentication, google-signin

I'm trying to create a simple Google SignIn button and when you press it, you are able to sign in with your google account. I am doing this using Google Firebase Authentication and I have enabled Google Sign-In (and Email/Password). However, I have run into multiple errors and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
[image]

This is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>GoogleSignUp</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="googleSignIn()">Google SignIn</button>
    <script
    src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script>
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "--------------",
    authDomain: "--------------",
    projectId: "productify-36d63",
    storageBucket: "--------------",
    messagingSenderId: "--------------",
    appId: "--------------,
    measurementId: "--------------"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

googleSignIn=()=>{
  base_provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(base_provider).then(function(result){
    console.log(result)
    console.log("Success... Google Account Linked")
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err)
    console.log("Failed")
  })
}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have no Errors until I actually click the button.
These are the errors that I get once I click the Sign-In Button:

[image]

I have looked everywhere, watched so many videos, read as much as I could from stackoverflow and have been trying to figure out how to create a google sign-in button using Firebase Authentication but nothings working.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the **app** and **auth** script

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first --> 
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

You can find out more in the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)